# Decrease process priority

Tags: macos, sublimetext

I develop rails applications on my iMac. Often executing all the specs using the parallel_tests gem. This gem uses multiple threads to run specs to utilise all CPU cores. During this, Sublime Text becomes very unresponsive, typing and scrolling is very jittery (e.g. there are *several seconds* delay between hitting the key and the letter appearing on the screen).

How can I make Sublime Text more responsive when all cpu resources are utilised?

What I tried so far:

- execute specs with "nice 20". Did not help. Seems no effect at all.
- renice Sublime to -20. Did not help. Seems no effect at all.
- use vim during test execution. Works flawlessly, there are no lags.

Comment: I'm not surprised nice had no effect. That's been deprecated and not used by the scheduler for quite some time. If `vi` gets enough CPU, it might be hard to influence the OS directly.